# have domain specified inside the links of pages generated with Umbraco

Tags: c#, web, content-management-system, umbraco, xslt

Not sure the title explains what I want to do, so here goes: I have a website constructed with Umbraco 4.5.x and the links in the pages use relative paths. I want to have the domain prepended to these links and don't know how to do that; I didn't really used Umbraco so I am a newby at this :(.

What I want to do is replace links like:

```
<a href="/about-us/who-we-are.aspx">Who we are...</a>
```

with something like:

```
<a href="http://www.our-domain.com/about-us/who-we-are.aspx">Who we are...</a>
```

or

```
<a href="www.our-domain.com/about-us/who-we-are.aspx">Who we are...</a>
```

What are the things that I must do for this? Is it all Umbraco configuration or do I need to write some code? Or both?

I found something about the [useDomainPrefixes](http://umbraco.org/documentation/books/running-multiple-websites-on-one-umbraco-installation-%281%29/setting-up-umbraco) config but it does not seem to work (not sure if it is even related to what I want to do).

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want this? What is the purpose/benifit?

Comment: @Andreas Paulsson: one reason would be this (http://www.search-this.com/2008/01/16/2-minute-seo-tip-absolute-vs-relative-links/). The other one is because I want my users that save one page locally to be able to have working links in the page they saved instead of an error because they did not download the pages for the links too.

Comment: In XSLT 1.0 the only way is passing URI as param. With XPath 2.0 you have `fn:document-uri()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this by using [Rewrite rules for IIS](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/), Inbound + Outbound.

I also tried with [NiceUrlFullPath](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/umbracolibrary/niceurlfullpath) but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using UrlAbsolutifierModule ( http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2007/12/14/urlabsolutifiermodule---convert-urls-in-asp.net-output-to-absolute.aspx ) or similar.